# How to deconflict non-secret and secret environment variables in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase Cloud Functions, which uses Google Cloud under the hood, and I have used Google Cloud's Secret Manager to define a few secrets for my web application.

I am accessing these secrets in my typescript code for the Firebase Functions like this:

```js
import {onRequest} from 'firebase-functions/v2/https';
import {defineSecret} from 'firebase-functions/params';
import * as logger from 'firebase-functions/logger';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as cors from 'cors';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const var1= defineSecret('VAR1');
const var2 = defineSecret('VAR2');
```

When I run `firebase deploy --only functions` I get this error:

```
i  functions: updating Node.js 18 (2nd Gen) function sendEmail(us-central1)...
!  functions: HTTP Error: 400, Could not update Cloud Run service projects/<myproject>/locations/us-central1/services/<myapi>. spec.template.spec.containers[0].env: Secret environment variable overlaps non secret environment variable: VAR1
!  functions:  failed to update function projects/<myproject>/locations/us-central1/functions/<myapi>
Failed to update function projects/<myproject>/locations/us-central1/functions/<myapi>

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        myapi(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
!  functions: Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually at https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/<myproject>/us/gcf

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

I tried deleting my `.env` file, I ran `firebase functions:config:unset VAR1 VAR2` and also ran `gcloud run services describe <myapi> --format='value(spec.template.spec.containers[0].env)'` which returned the secrets defined in Google Cloud.

I can't figure out how to identify the overlapping "non-secret" and "secret" environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by removing enviornment variables defined in the Google Cloud Run Service. I am not sure how or why these ever got defined in Google Cloud Run Service.

1. Go to the Cloud Run section of the Google Cloud Console.
2. Select the project and navigate to the service in question.
3. Click on the service to go to its details page.
4. Click "Edit & deploy new revision".
5. Scroll down to the "Variables & Secrets" section.
6. Here, you can remove environment variables by clicking the trash icon next to the variable you wish to delete.
7. After making your changes, click "Deploy" to update the service with the new configuration.